# will a virtual box file on windows work on a mac?

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

if I move a vm form a windows machine to a mac machine, will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should, assuming you copy the configuration file as well as the hard drive file, and any required CD/DVD images as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they are both running the same version, then click on the export menu item on the win machine, transfer the resulting files and click on import on the Mac.